# Botium Box crawler test case failing on Watson Assistant buttons

Tags: automated-tests, chatbot, botium-box

I am using Botium Box crawler on a Watson Assistant skill.
The bot's initial statement includes a greeting and seven buttons.
Botium is generating test cases for each of the buttons, but the button-press does not generate the right response in Watson Assistant.

A generated case is below:

```
1.6.2.2.2.4_hello_Password

#bot

#me
hello

#bot
UTT_M1_HI-THERE!

#bot
BUTTONS Benefits|Badges, Explanation of Badges or Certificate of Completion|COVID-19|ID Cards - Order, View, Print, Return|Employment/Termination|Password|None of the above, enter search text

#me
BUTTON password|Password

#bot
(responds as if Watson Assistant received the word "BUTTON" rather than the "password" value in "Password"-labeled button)
```

The dialog node has child responses using conditions like:

```
input.text=="password" or input.text.contains("password")
```

The expected behavior in Watson Assistant for a button press is that the button text (not label) is passed to the button.  In the Watson Assistant Try it Out panel I click "Password" and it sends the text "password".

The only way I can replicate the Botium behavior in Try it Out is to pass the literal text "BUTTON".  Even if Botium sent input.text=="BUTTON password|Password" my condition should fire.

Am I using Botium Box crawler wrong, or is there a bug in the crawler?

Update: Other button-driven prompts work, such as "yes/no" button prompts.  I wonder if there is a parsing problem because the buttons have very long labels with some special characters and punctuation.

Comment: thanks for the detailed analysis. Will investigate on this.

Comment: Can you pls post the Botium log output, it will show what payload is actually sent to Watson from Botium

Comment: Checked the code - actually in this case the text "password" should be sent to the Watson assistant. verbose log output should confirm this for further investigation

Comment: Regular or verbose log output does not give much detail (apologies for formatting) 
* 2021-05-24T13:46:29.932Z: Crawler Job 'hello' queued for execution
* 2021-05-24T13:46:32.385Z: Started processing, JobId #383623, with 'hello entry point.
* 2021-05-24T14:33:46.419Z: Running Botium Crawler with 'hello entry point is finished successfully.
* 2021-05-24T14:33:48.261Z: Job completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has to be fixed with the next release of the crawler package.
If you need this fix now, then we can update directly your trial instance.

Comment: Thank you, I'd appreciate if you could update the trial instance in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more detailed log by set the DEBUG=botium-* env variable. So in commandline it should look like this:

```
DEBUG=botium-* botium-cli crawler-run --entryPoints 'hello'
```

In this case you will get a log and very detailed log. You can reduce its size with using exitCriteria (e.g.: `--exitCriteria 'Benefits' 'Badges'`) to exclude those path which work correctly.
We will investigate the detailed log, just send us please.

Comment: I'm using the hosted version - I don't see where to put that `DEBUG` setting.  I clicked the "Start Crawler Session (Extended Logging) Now" button, with the assumption it would be equivalent.  But, I do not see any extra logging with that.

Comment: ah, that makes a difference - what instance are you using ?

Comment: us.ibm.botiumbox.com

Comment: Szabi is actually working on this one - for future inqueries for product support, I suggest to use the Botium Box forum instead of Stackoverflow - https://forum.botium.ai/